# LoadImage (Win32) returns 0x06 error

Tags: c#, winapi, loadimage

I'm new to Win32 API.
I'm trying use the win32 API. When I load an image I get a handle back, but I also get GetLastError response 0x06, invalid handle. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="LoadImage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadImage(IntPtr hinst, string lpszName, uint uType,
       int cxDesired, int cyDesired, uint fuLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint ="GetLastError", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint GetLastError();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\bitmap.bmp";
        IntPtr pointer = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, path, 0, 256, 256, 0x00008010);
        uint result = GetLastError();
        Console.WriteLine(pointer);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output reads i.e.:

```
-1576718263
6
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I wanted to configure the call to load the image from file, and also have shared handle as I'll be using that handle though the application.

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: [The documentation for `LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) does not ascribe any meaning to `GetLastError` if the function succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call `GetLastError` if the function has *failed,* as indicated by the return value. From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle of the newly loaded image.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Calling it when the function has *succeeded* is meaningless.

You would be better off with something like:

```
IntPtr pointer = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, path, 0, 256, 256, 0x00008010);
if (pointer == NULL) {
    uint result = GetLastError();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Keep in mind that, as some people have pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't call `GetLastError` from managed code. Instead, you should set `SetLastError` to `true` and then use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks so I can assume I've succeeded getting the handle. This was confusing for me. As the GetLastError() can be 0 meaning no error

Comment: @mac671, yes, unless the handle is NULL, you have succeeded. The GetLastError is to get _extra_ information (reason for failure) only if the function failed.

Comment: As a general rule, winapi functions don't set the error code when they succeed, only when they fail (this may even be true of all of them but I can't say off the top of my head). The documentation of each function will tell you what happens when they succeed or fail.

Comment: In managed code you must use SetLastError = true and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error and never call GetLastError directly

Comment: @David, good point, added to the answer. Thanks.